# Meteor.loginWithToken() on Server

Tags: ios, meteor, ddp

On the **server** I have the following code:

```
var userId = Accounts.createUser({"email": email});
var stampedLoginToken = Accounts._generateStampedLoginToken();
Accounts._insertLoginToken(userId, stampedLoginToken);
```

Calling `Meteor.loginWithToken(stampedLoginToken)` doesn't work since `loginWithToken` only available on Client. My questions:

1) Is it possible to use `loginWithToken` on server side?

2) If I can't use `loginWithToken`, are there any other ways I can simulate a user login?

Thanks.

Note: I'm using a third-party iOS DDP client [github.com/martijnwalraven/meteor-ios](http://github.com/martijnwalraven/meteor-ios)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only perform programmatic login on client side, see [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_loginwithexternalservice): to the right from the method name, there's "Client" label which means that the method can only run on client side.

You can't log in a user on the server and expect them to become logged in on the client because Meteor wouldn't know what exact client should be logged in. Moreover, it relies on some sort of session variables, therefore cannot be performed on the server side.

The only thing you can do is to perform login on the client side.